# Capturing audio using DirectShow

Tags: c#, audio, directshow

I'm writing program which captures audio in C# using DirectShow library and writes it to ogg container. I created a graph in GraphEditPlus. It generates a GraphBuilder method code which I copied to my code. This code is:

```
class AudioCapture
{
  public static void checkHR(int hr, string msg)
  {
    if (hr < 0)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(msg);
      DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    }
  }

  public static void BuildGraph (IGraphBuilder pGraph, string dstFile)
  {
    int hr = 0;

    //graph builder
    ICaptureGraphBuilder2 pBuilder = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
    hr = pBuilder.SetFiltergraph(pGraph);
    checkHR(hr, "Can't SetFiltergraph");

    Guid CLSID_XiphOrgVorbisEncoder = new Guid("{5C94FE86-B93B-467F-BFC3-BD6C91416F9B}");
    Guid CLSID_XiphOrgOggMuxer = new Guid("{1F3EFFE4-0E70-47C7-9C48-05EB99E20011}");

    //add microphone
    IBaseFilter pMicrophone = (IBaseFilter) new AudioRecord();
    hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pMicrophone, "Microphone");
    checkHR(hr, "Can't add microphone to graph");

    //add Vorbis Encoder
    IBaseFilter pVorbisEncoder = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_XiphOrgVorbisEncoder));
    checkHR(hr, "Can't add Vorbis Encoder to graph");

    //connect Microphone and Vorbis Encoder
    hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pMicrophone, "Capture"), GetPin(pVorbisEncoder, "PCM In"), null);
    checkHR(hr, "Can't connect Microphone and Vorbis Encoder");

    //add Ogg Muxer
    IBaseFilter pOggMuxer = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_XiphOrgOggMuxer));
    checkHR(hr, "Can't add Ogg Muxer to graph");

    //set destination filename
    IFileSinkFilter pOggMuxer_sink = pOggMuxer as IFileSinkFilter;
    if (pOggMuxer_sink == null)
      checkHR(unchecked((int)0x80004002), "Can't get IFileSinkFilter");
    hr = pOggMuxer_sink.SetFileName(dstFile, null);
    checkHR(hr, "Can't set filename");

    //connect Vorbis Encoder and Ogg Muxer
    hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pVorbisEncoder, "VorbisOut"), GetPin(pOggMuxer, "Ogg Packet In"), null);
    checkHR(hr, "Can't connect Vorbis Encoder and Ogg Muxer");
  }

  static IPin GetPin(IBaseFilter filter, string pinname)
  {
    IEnumPins epins;
    int hr = filter.EnumPins(out epins);
    checkHR(hr, "Can't enumerate pins");
    IntPtr fetched = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
    IPin[] pins = new IPin[1];
    while (epins.Next(1, pins, fetched) == 0)
    {
      PinInfo pinfo;
      pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out pinfo);
      bool found = (pinfo.name == pinname);
      DsUtils.FreePinInfo(pinfo);
      if (found)
        return pins[0];
    }
    checkHR(-1, "Pin not found");
    return null;
  }
}
```

When I'm trying to execute this code program throws me a message "Pin can't found" after trying to connect microphone and vorbis encoder filters. After debugging I found out that it can't find the microphone pin. Does anybody knows where is my error?

Comment: It is better to search for the audio input device. just `new AudioRecord()` does not automatically create the micropone input.

Comment: Hi how to record both video and audio  and into save it into a single video file? I am able to do it by separeate files. can u help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not look for pins by their names, as this is not quite reliable. Perhaps it might be still more or less acceptable if you are absolutely sure what filter/class you are dealing with, but it is definitely not the way to do with generic audio source filter (more specifically: noone gives a promise that capture pin is named "Capture", instead pins implement `IKsPropertySet` to indicate that).

Your best approach would be using `ICaptureGraphBuilder::RenderStream` with `PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE` argument so that it could pick up capture pin for you. See MSDN for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd311932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and I am pretty sure you will easily find sample code for doing this too.

Answer (score 0):

Try do something like this when you looking for pins

```
    pinout = FindPinByDirection( Source, PinDirection.Output);
    pinin = FindPinByDirection( Target, PinDirection.Input);

    Graph.Connect(pinout, pinin);
```

This is better way then depending on names.